# bridge edge loops causing creases at the corners of my mesh

Tags: modeling, edges

The corners are getting creased when I expect them to be smooth. how do i avoid this?

[image: red portion are where the creases are formed and it wont go away even after smooth shading andauto smooth normal (30)]

[image: same sink in solid mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the *LoopTools* addon, select your circle at the bottom of your mesh and right click > *LoopTools > Circle*, rotate it a bit on Z if necessary. Also, maybe you should use less faces to model your object, it would make it easier.

Comment: how can I model the mesh with fewer vertices without giving up on curve resolutions?

Comment: You could use a Subdivision Surface modifier, but if you can't for some reason, sure, what you've done is OK